# How to do hypothesis testing for many individual means over time?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, panel-data

There is a data set that has yearly data for mean values of the number of ice creams eaten for 5 persons. The data set has values for 5 persons and 5 years(5x5 panel). Suppose due to some theory it is assumed that mean value for the sample should be 50 units of ice creams (null hypothesis). How to perform a hypothesis test for this sample. ***Please help***. *Thank you.*

Answer (score 2):

You can assume that number of icecreams eaten per person in each year follows a normal distribution such as $N(\mu_1,\sigma_1^{2})..,N(\mu_5,\sigma_5^{2})$,where $\mu_1,...,\mu_5$ and $\sigma_1^{2},...,\sigma_5^{2}$ are population means and variances respectively.Then for each of the 5 years you will get 5 samples from the normal populations.So,in this case,your required test is $H_0:\mu_1=\mu_2=...=\mu_5=50$ against $\mu_{i}$'s are not equal.

Now you draw a random sample of 5 persons for each year.Let $x_{i1},x_{i2},...,x_{i5}$ be the random sample drawn from the ith population.
By likelihood ratio test you can get the required test statistic as,

$\lambda_x(\theta)=(\frac{1}{1+\frac{SSB}{SSW}})^{\frac{n}{2}}$,$\sum n_{i}=n,i=1(1)5.$  **where,**

$SSB=\frac{1}{5}\sum\sum(\bar x_{i0}-\bar x_{00})^2$

$SSW=\frac{1}{5}\sum\sum(\bar x_{ij}-\bar x_{i0})^2$,$\bar x_{i0}=\frac{\sum x{ij}}{n_i}$ and $\bar x_{00}=\frac{\sum\sum x{ij}}{\sum n_i}$

As,$\lambda_{x}(\theta)$ is a decreasing function of $\frac{SSB}{SSW}$,we reject $H_0$ when $\lambda(x)<C$ i,e,. $T=\frac{MSB}{MSW}>C'$,$MSB=\frac{SSB}{5-1}$,$,MSW=\frac{SSW}{n-5}$,where $T\backsim F_{(k-1,n-k)},$under $H_0.$

Under $H_0,C'=F_{\alpha;5-1,n-5}$,$\alpha$ is the desired level of significance.

Comment: Please also suggest how to do this in R or any other software?